# How to generate only a Gemfile in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler, rbenv

Using rbenv so the process of creating a new app is a bit convoluted:

1. Create directory
2. cd directory
3. Set ruby version: `rbenv local 1.9.3-p125` (or other version)
4. Set gemset: `echo project-name > .rbenv-gemsets`
5. `gem install rails -v 3.2.2 --no-rdoc --no-ri` (for example)
6. `rbenv rehash`
7. `echo "gem 'rails', '3.2.2'" > Gemfile`
8. `bundle`
9. `rails new .` (Enter y to overwrite)
10. `bundle`

This worked before, but this time I got an error on the `rails new .` command:

```
...
...
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
create  vendor/plugins
create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
run  bundle install
b/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Running `rails new .` a second time throws

`Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.`

What is the best way to initialize a new Rails app if it's not possible to do `rails new app-name`?

How to create just the Gemfile? If I had the correct Rails Gemfile, then `bundle` and `rails new .` should work...

Comment: The problem seems to be the installing of jquery-rails. Did you try running bundle again?

Answer (score 1):

After you've ran `rails new` and it mostly succeded (with the exception of the final `bundle` command), it's not necessary to generate the Rails app again.

You seem to have done everything right. Your only problem is that a single gem could not be installed. You should try running `bundle install` again, and if that still doesn't work, check that you have `source 'https://rubygems.org'` in the Gemfile and perhaps `rm -r .bundle` to delete any local Bundler settings.